# Should I alter the CSS code of front-end frameworks?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

What is the best practice to customize a front-end framework? What if I want to change the background color of a div or have a higher border radius for example? Would I create a new class in the stylesheet? Add my own stylesheet with custom classes, add inline css, etc...

I realize all these options are possible, my question is what is considered best practice.

(I'm using Zurb Foundation).

Comment: It really depends on will you ever update your framework in the future. If not: change properties directly, otherwise add new stylesheet and there add your styles. Never use inline css if you do not have to.

Comment: While there's *some* opinion here, this is a valid question and has real answers depending on the use-case.  Either this, or the duplicate, should not have been closed.